NPM Error while adding overrides for a dependency
I have multiple dependencies related to a UI framework I am using as below
"@my-ui-fwk/ag-grid-theme": "^1.3.7",
"@my-ui-fwk/core": "1.16.0",
"@my-ui-fwk/data-grid": "^1.0.3",
"@my-ui-fwk/icons": "1.9.1",
"@my-ui-fwk/lab": "^1.0.0-alpha.29",
"@my-ui-fwk/theme": "1.11.0",

Now, I want to ensure that only 1 version of "@my-ui-fwk/core" i.e. "1.16.0" is used.
So when I run npm list, I get below;
$ npm list @my-ui-fwk/core
+-- @my-ui-fwk/core@1.16.0
+-- @my-ui-fwk/data-grid@1.0.3
| +-- @my-ui-fwk/core@1.4.0
| `-- @my-ui-fwk/lab@1.0.0-alpha.4
|   `-- @my-ui-fwk/core@1.4.0 deduped
`-- @my-ui-fwk/lab@1.0.0-alpha.38
  `-- @my-ui-fwk/core@1.22.0

Now to fix i.e. ensure that only 1 version of "@my-ui-fwk/core", I add the following to my package.json
"overrides": {
    "@my-ui-fwk/data-grid": {
      "@my-ui-fwk/core": "$@my-ui-fwk/core"
    },
    "@my-ui-fwk/lab": {
      "@my-ui-fwk/core": "$@my-ui-fwk/core"
    }
}

However, after adding above overrides and when I do npm install again and run npm list, I am getting below error;
npm list @my-ui-fwk/core
npm ERR! code ELSPROBLEMS
npm ERR! invalid: @my-ui-fwk/core@1.22.0 D:\my-ui-web\node_modules\@my-ui-fwk\lab\node_modules\@my-ui-fwk\core
my-ui-web@0.1.0 D:\my-ui-web
+-- @my-ui-fwk/core@1.16.0 overridden
+-- @my-ui-fwk/data-grid@1.0.3 overridden
| +-- @my-ui-fwk/core@1.16.0 deduped
| `-- @my-ui-fwk/lab@1.0.0-alpha.4 overridden
|   `-- @my-ui-fwk/core@1.16.0 deduped
`-- @my-ui-fwk/lab@1.0.0-alpha.38 overridden
  `-- @my-ui-fwk/core@1.22.0 invalid: "1.16.0" from node_modules/@my-ui-fwk/lab overridden

Please let me know if the above is not the correct way to add 'overrides'
UPDATED
Actual issue I am trying to solve is this;
Basically I have my HTML element as below
<html lang="en" class="my-theme my-density-medium" data-mode="light">

While initially it loads as above...But on certain UI interactions (e.g. dropdown open/close), the data-mode becomes "undefined" and causes the page CSS to break completely.
<html lang="en" class="my-theme my-density-medium" data-mode="undefined">

As a fix, I was told that I need to ensure same version for "@my-ui-fwk/core" even for any sub-dependencies.

Rather than using overrides, have you considered adding @my-ui-fwk/core as a peer dependency within your subprojects? Then it wouldn't install @my-ui-fwk/core for each subproject you depend on, instead having those modules rely on you having @my-ui-fwk/core separately available in your node_modules (i.e. the implementing project's "core version").

Thanks....Actually I do not have control over the deps in my subproject e.g. I cannot control @my-ui-fwk/data-grid in this case

From a closer look on the error, you have a subproject dependency with a newer version than your current dependencies (you have 1.16.0, but your dependency is using 1.22.0). Would it not be better to depend on 1.22.0, moving the older subproject dependencies forward, rather than reverting a dependency that explicitly listed 1.22.0? Otherwise from a quick glance, I think we're taking a dive to npm's actual handling for the override config parameter.

Yeah...actually there is a specific theming issue I am trying to resolve...and the suggested resolution is to have same version of my-ui-fwk/core

Mind adding the details about the theming issue?

Yeah....updated in original question

I'll be posting a short answer, but I don't think it will truly "answer" the question as much as offer some thoughts. Be wary of the XY problem, there's more solutions than simply enforcing the same versioning.

That said, posting more about your actual code as a concrete example is helpful in providing a better answer.

Thanks...Actually the issue is related to this post (though I do not find the actual solution here)
https://github.com/jpmorganchase/salt-ds/issues/1325

(This is not an answer! But it is a very long comment that hopes to help the question improve)
So it sounds like your real question is that a mismatch in dependencies lead to one call being undefined (likely as it didn't exist in the same way). You face the same issue in reverse when moving things forward to 1.22.0: if your core broke backwards compatibility, then older plugins will get undefined/errors when attempting their calls. JS is duck-typed for good reason here: if your subproject's code has a separate core dependency but produces the same intermediate responses, there's no problem (Aside from space consumption).
To get in front of this issue there are several approaches, but in the end it will come down to design decisions within your framework. My personal opinion would be that you define an external interface for utilizing your modules, such that the interface itself doesn't need to change much. If it does, those changes would be largely additive with removals being slow and purposeful. You can then change the underlying implementation to fit your needs.
Enforcing all of your subprojects onto the same version can work, but that comes with an implicit cost: you have essentially required that all projects and subprojects have the same version for the end user as well. This may be desirable, but you now have the development overhead of updating each individual subproject when a high-level dependency has a version change. It may be best to simply allow for the subprojects to proliferate the node_modules during development, but then use peer dependencies for deployed stable releases. This way, you "synchronize" the versions for those releases, but the overhead of doing so comes when you have an actual version to release.
In the end, it's easier to think about these things with actual concrete examples. There may in fact be a simpler solution than any of this available to you depending on what is becoming undefined in the javascript itself.

Thanks for the details....For the actual detailed issue, you can refer https://github.com/jpmorganchase/salt-ds/issues/1325
However, I am not able to find a proper solution on this link

Also, I am consuming this...So do not really have control over how it defines it package/dep versions

As a "best practice" you may wish to stick with dependency versions which have matching subdependencies to begin with. This may mean not taking their latest version available, but it would sidestep this particular pitfall. It sounds like a deficit of the framework you are utilizing in not maintaining a consistent external interface, such that version changes cause these fundamental mismatches.
